# OneToMany ManyToOne JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to make OneToMany and ManyToOne mapping but I'm getting this Bad Request, I'm using Swagger to generate request body, the thing that I dont understand is that in RelvLineEntity I'm injecting BankSheetEntity as One and cleary it should take the BankSheetEntity Id as a FK that means in request body inside RelvLineEntity should had a field type Long of bankSheetId but when I'm trying to make a POST, inside RelvLineEntity it shows as following: `"releveBancaire": "string"` See it should have a Long type not a String that's why it shows :

```
(although at least one
> Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to
> deserialize from String value ('string')
```

I tried to change to Long I get 500. Tried to pass null and nothing works.
*

> "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of
> `releve.domain.domain.BankSheet` (although at least one
> Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to
> deserialize from String value ('string'); nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> construct instance of `releve.domain.domain.BankSheet`
> (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument
> constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value
> ('string')\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 64, column: 25]
> (through reference chain:
> releve.domain.domain.BankSheet["RelvLine"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->releve.domain.domain.RelvLine["BankSheet"])",

- 

These are my entities:

```
public class BankSheetEntity {

        @Id
        private Long bankSheetId;
        ....///

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "bankSheet", targetEntity = RelvLineEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<RelvLineEntity> relvLine;
}
```

==================================================================================

```
public class RelvLineEntity{


    @Id
    private Long relvLineId;
    ....///

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "bank_sheet_FK", referencedColumnName = "bankSheetId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private BankSheetEntity bankSheet;
```

I think this is the right mapping of OneToMany and ManyToOne, any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson is telling you it needs some way to create entities from the String values it's getting. Try adding no-argument and full argument constructors to both entities.

Comment: All my enteties have noArg constructor and allArg constructor and all are public, if this exeption needs more details i'll update